# Bundle items not showing in cart

Tags: cart, database, bundled-product

I have a bundle product with a number of bundled items all with default amount 1.

For some reason, Magento is only showing 1 (the first one) of my bundled items in the cart!

I have a local Magento installation with the exact same files though not the same database, and the products show fine on my local installation?

Why won't Magento show all my products?  I tried Disabling/Re-enabling, in-stock/out-of-stock, refreshing index and cache...

Comment: Can you narrow it down? What's the difference between the two databases?

Comment: One is a production site with live orders, and one is a local site for testing, therefore the main differences are customers.  However, there may be differences in how administrators have set up products.  Which tables should I look in for differences in terms of product attributes/options, and any commands I can use to aid in this search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem! Thanks to fschmengler for putting me on the right track.

It was an caching/SID issue!

Symptoms to reproduce: **Magento Blocks HTML caching is turned on (only when turned on)**

An SID parameter was being added to the URL that I couldn't see, and was being added in between query parameters in a way that messed everything up.

How to fix, add '_nosid' => true to URL params:

```
$params = array('_query'=> $query,'qty' => 1, '_nosid' => true);
```

Then the add to cart URL can be retrieved by

```
Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product, $params)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to dig into the database to find out the difference in product configuration between the two systems, these tables are relevant for bundle products:

- `catalog_product_bundle_option` (configuration of bundle options)
- `catalog_product_bundle_selection` (selections, i.e. products associated to the options)

But what probably makes more sense is to do it like this:

- dump the production db and import it on your local installation (backup the local db first!)
- change as much as you need to be able to test (base URLs, cookie domain...)
- flush cache

Now you should have exactly the same behavior locally than on the production system. If not, the problem was not in the database.

Other things to consider:

- Different PHP versions
- Different operating systems
- Caching layers outside of Magento, like APC opcode cache

Also, if you didn't already, look into the log files on both systems (Magento logs in var/log as well as webserver logs to check for PHP errors). Make sure that error logging is enabled in Magento (system configuration) and in PHP (php.ini)

Comment: Yes!  This is a great answer!  It seems that it must be a different version of PHP issue, since I don't have the problem even with the same database imported on my local machine.
The URLs are getting generated differently:
The correct URL:
qty/1/?bundle_option[4][]=11&bundle_option[4][]=12&bundle_option[4][]=13&bundle_option[4][]=14&bundle_option[4][]=15&bundle_option[4][]=16&

What I'm getting:
qty/1/?%23038%3B=&%23038%3Bbundle_option%5B4%5D%5B%5D=16&bundle_option%5B4%5D%5B%5D=11

Comment: This means the whole query string has been URL encoded (instead of just the single parameters, which is done by default in HTML forms) - maybe this information helps you, I am not sure which settings could cause such behavior.